# Is there any better way to get information from other website than curl?

Tags: php, mysql, optimization, curl

One website stores information in ids, like that `http://website.com/index.php?id=1`. It has about 500,000 records.

I need to retrieve them and put it in database (MySQL). Now I use curl and it gets that information, but it's very slow. I got only ~4,000 records in one hour.

My question, is there any way to do this faster?

Comment: What's the bottleneck? If connection/processing time, maybe you can grab several in parallel (multiple scripts running, for example). If bandwidth limit, too bad.

Comment: why curl is slow for you ? May be you need multithread ?

Comment: Do you have permission to scrape this website? most site operators are NOT going to be happy if you suck out 500,000 records as fast as you possibly can.

Comment: it mean that you may be want estabilish connections in parallel, 10-100 connecions in one time, to fetch the pages.

Comment: I'd say so... they might have defensive systems and blacklist your IP after a few hundred records, then you're up the proverbial creek without a paddle.

Comment: 4,000 records in one hour : if I was the admin of that server this would be enough to blacklist you, you should try to get less and looks like  a human surfing on the website, like 1,000 each days, in working hours, with right headers -- or ask them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're not against using perl, the CPAN module Web::Scraper is the conventional way for scraping pages efficiently. See http://metacpan.org/pod/Web::Scraper .

Answer (score 0):

use [`JSONP`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP)
One More [`JSON With Padding`](http://ajaxian.com/archives/jsonp-json-with-padding)

Comment: How would this help? (I'm not suggesting that it won't; I'm wondering what problem this addresses.)

Answer (score 0):

You could always use `wget` in combination with the `exec` function in php. This of course assumes you have configured your server to allow php to execute shell commands. However, `wget` is significantly faster than `curl`.